# How do fix the "Cannot find 'NSFetchRequest' in scope error

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, nsfetchrequest

I have tried to make an NSFetchRequest in many different ways and each time I get this error:

"Cannot find type 'NSFetchRequest' in scope"

Here are the specific ways I have tried:

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Task")

let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Task> = Task.NSFetchRequest()

let fetchRequest = Task.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<Task>
```

Any idea why this is giving me this error? I know it's unlikely;iklely but I'm on the Xcode 12 beta, could this be a bug with Xcode? I followed a tutorial as I am just learning SwiftUI (and Swift in general) and so it would seem to me this code should work. I have looked in many places to try to find an answer to this so if it's obvious, I'm sorry I missed it.

Comment: Have you added `import CoreData` to your file?

Comment: That did it. I feel so stupid but hey at least I'm learning. Interesting that the tutorial glossed over that step. Thank you so much!

Comment: Don’t feel bad. If the tutorial doesn’t show it then it’s not an easy leap for a learner. Enjoy your trip :-)

Answer (score 23):

**Cannot find * in scope**

There are several reasons why this error might appear in your code.

1. You didn't import the framework
2. If you are using cocoapods, the pod might not be installed.
3. You opened the .xcodeproj file instead of the .xcworkspace file (If you are using cocoapods)
4. The variable does not exist
5. The file was not added to target

**#1 You didn't import the framework.**

If the first option is the case, you need to look up which framework is used by the object/method. If it is an external framework (not shipped with Xcode), it might be a good idea to take a look at the site you got the code from / contact the developer if you got it from GitHub.

**#2 If you are using cocoapods, the pod might not be installed**

To install cocoapods in your Xcode project, you need to open a new Terminal window. There, you need to navigate to your Xcode project. To do so, just type in `cd /path/to/your/xcodeproject`. Then you can type `pod init`. If there is an error saying `-bash: pod: command not found`, then cocoapods is not installed. To install it, just type `sudo gem install cocoapods`. Then `pod init` should work just fine. This command creates a file called `Podfile`. Open it and add `pod 'name-of-your-pod'`. Save and close the file. Back in the terminal, type `pod install`. This will now take some time depending on the size of the pods. When it is done, there should be a .xcworkspace file. From now on, you need to open that instead of the standard .xcodeproj file.

**#3 You opened the .xcodeproj file instead of the .xcworkspace file (If you are using cocoapods)**

If you are using cocoapods, those pods are only used by Xcode when you open the .xcworkspace file - just open it, and you're good to go!

**#4 The variable does not exist**

You forgot to create the variable you're trying to access. To create it, just type `var myVar = "myString"` if you want to change it or replace `var` with `let` if it will never be changed. You also need to replace `"myString"` with your desired value. Another reason could be that you defined the variable you are trying to access inside of a closure, meaning that it cannot be accessed from outside. To avoid that, define your variable before the closure.

**#5 The file was not added to target**

In order for Xcode to know what to include when building your app, it uses so-called "targets". If your file is not added to any target, the compiler will fail to find the file. To add your file to a target, select the file, and on the pane on the right, select Target Membership -> (YourAppName). Rebuilding the project should fix the issue (thanks to @Sravan for pointing this out).

Comment: #5, if the file is not added to target. Make sure you add the file to the respective target. you can check the same in Build Phases too.

Comment: #5 It works earlier but after incorrect merge of project file. This issue happens :)

Answer (score 7):

Had this same error for about an hour now,

```swift
import CoreData
```

You would be missing this line if it says its out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

If that error happens in a swift file and if you are in a project with .swift files and objective c files, maybe you need to add the .h to your bridging-header file

Comment: This worked for me. I didn't import the missing file in `Runner-Bridging-Header.h`. Flutter environment.

Answer (score 1):

I came accross this error when working on a multiplatform app. Everything works fine for macOS builds, but throws this error for iOS builds.

Adding `import CoreData` seems to be necessary for iOS, when it is not needed for macOS.